# Adding Connections on Linkedin with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to add connections on Linkedin with Selenium.

I am running into a problem when I try to click each "Connect Now" button. There is a small window that pops up and the script isn't able to click the button. I have tried to click the link and then use `driver.find_element_by_class_name('button-primary-large ml1').click()`

Side question - How do I connect large and ml1?

When I run the code, it is clicking to connect but then it has a problem trying to click "Send Now" which is what the code above is trying to do. What is a good way for me to click the send now button? I am posting pictures to show what I mean.
[image: Trying to Connect with this link]

Answer (score 0):

You can click the button by using

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.send-invite__actions button.button-primary-large').click()
```